# ERROR no room on ep ring with USB 3.0 device

Tags: usb, hardware, mythbuntu, xhci-hcd

Just did a clean install of mythbuntu 12.04 yesterday on a brand new machine. ASRock Z77 Extreme4 with Intel video chipset, 8gb ram.

I'm seeing google references to this as a USB 3 issue in this driver but as I'm using stock 12.04 I wanted to at least get a bug ref for ubuntu.

Entire dmesg is filled with:

```
[22822.772021] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR no room on ep ring
[22822.772024] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR no room on ep ring
[22822.772027] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR no room on ep ring
[22822.772030] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR no room on ep ring
[22822.772034] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR no room on ep ring
[22822.772037] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR no room on ep ring
```

Information about my system:

```
root@mythtv:~# uname -a
Linux mythtv 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@mythtv:~# lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
  Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 0100
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
  Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
  Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
  Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 0102
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 54
  Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
  Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
  I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
  Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
  Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
  Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
  Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
  Kernel driver in use: i915
  Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
  Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1e31
  Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
  Memory at f7f00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
  Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
  Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
  Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
  Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1e3a
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 53
  Memory at f7f1a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
  Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
  Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
  Kernel driver in use: mei
  Kernel modules: mei

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
  Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1e2d
  Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
  Memory at f7f18000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
  Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
  Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
  Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
  Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
  Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1898
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 55
  Memory at f7f10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
  Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
  Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
  Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
  Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
  Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
  Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
  Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
  I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
  Memory behind bridge: dfb00000-dfcfffff
  Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000dfd00000-00000000dfefffff
  Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
  Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
  Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1e10
  Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
  Kernel driver in use: pcieport
  Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
  Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
  I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
  Memory behind bridge: f7e00000-f7efffff
  Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
  Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
  Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1e16
  Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
  Kernel driver in use: pcieport
  Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
  Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
  Memory behind bridge: f7d00000-f7dfffff
  Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f4200000-00000000f42fffff
  Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
  Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
  Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1e18
  Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
  Kernel driver in use: pcieport
  Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
  Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
  Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0000000-00000000f40fffff
  Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
  Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
  Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1e1a
  Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
  Kernel driver in use: pcieport
  Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
  Bus: primary=00, secondary=06, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
  Memory behind bridge: f7c00000-f7cfffff
  Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
  Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
  Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1e1e
  Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
  Kernel driver in use: pcieport
  Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
  Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1e26
  Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
  Memory at f7f17000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
  Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
  Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
  Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
  Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
  Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1e44
  Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
  Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
  Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
  Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1e02
  Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
  I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
  I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
  I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
  I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
  I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
  Memory at f7f16000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
  Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
  Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
  Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
  Capabilities: [b0] PCI Advanced Features
  Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
  Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1e22
  Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
  Memory at f7f15000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
  I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
  Kernel modules: i2c-i801

02:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
  Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 0612
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
  I/O ports at e050 [size=8]
  I/O ports at e040 [size=4]
  I/O ports at e030 [size=8]
  I/O ports at e020 [size=4]
  I/O ports at e000 [size=32]
  Memory at f7e00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512]
  Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
  Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
  Capabilities: [80] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
  Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
  Kernel driver in use: ahci

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57781 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
  Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 96b1
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
  Memory at f4210000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
  Memory at f4200000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
  Expansion ROM at f7d00000 [disabled] [size=2K]
  Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
  Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
  Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=5 Masked-
  Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
  Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
  Capabilities: [13c] Device Serial Number 00-00-bc-5f-f4-56-ce-ab
  Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
  Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
  Kernel driver in use: tg3
  Kernel modules: tg3

04:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 03) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
  Bus: primary=04, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=32
  Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0000000-00000000f40fffff
  Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1080

05:00.0 Multimedia video controller: Brooktree Corporation Bt878 Video Capture (rev 11)
  Subsystem: Avermedia Technologies Inc AverTV DVB-T
  Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 17
  Memory at f4001000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
  Capabilities: [44] Vital Product Data
  Capabilities: [4c] Power Management version 2
  Kernel driver in use: bttv
  Kernel modules: bttv

05:00.1 Multimedia controller: Brooktree Corporation Bt878 Audio Capture (rev 11)
  Subsystem: Avermedia Technologies Inc AVerTV DVB-T
  Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 17
  Memory at f4000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
  Capabilities: [44] Vital Product Data
  Capabilities: [4c] Power Management version 2
  Kernel driver in use: bt878
  Kernel modules: bt878

05:01.0 Multimedia video controller: Internext Compression Inc iTVC16 (CX23416) Video Decoder (rev 01)
  Subsystem: Hauppauge computer works Inc. WinTV PVR 150
  Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 18
  Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]
  Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
  Kernel driver in use: ivtv
  Kernel modules: ivtv

06:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
  Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1042
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
  Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
  Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
  Capabilities: [68] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=8 Masked-
  Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
  Capabilities: [80] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
  Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
  Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

Answer (score 6):

This bug is already reported at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/883646.

You can mark yourself as affected by clicking on the yellow icon besides the text **Does this bug affect you?**, and then clicking on **Yes, it affects me**.

---

A workaround is suggested [here](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=101903), which suggests plugging a USB 2.0 device in the USB 3.0 port during startup.

---

**Update**: **Instructions for installing a newer kernel.** (see comments for the reason for posting this).

*Assumption: You're using a 64-bit machine.*

Go to http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4-precise/ and download the following files (or simply click on them):

- [linux-headers-3.4.0-030400-generic_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_amd64.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4-precise/linux-headers-3.4.0-030400-generic_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_amd64.deb)
- [linux-headers-3.4.0-030400_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_all.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4-precise/linux-headers-3.4.0-030400_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_all.deb)
- [linux-image-3.4.0-030400-generic_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_amd64.deb](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4-precise/linux-image-3.4.0-030400-generic_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_amd64.deb)

Then, just install them:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.4.0-030400-generic_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.4.0-030400_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.4.0-030400-generic_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_amd64.deb
```

**For more information, go here:** http://blog.hostonnet.com/how-to-install-linux-kernel-3-4-0-on-ubuntu-12-04-11-10.

Comment: So according to the bug report, it goes away in 3.4.0-030400-generic any suggestion how to get this into mythbuntu distribution? The workaround about using random devices in 3.0 slots is nonsensical. Thanks!

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: perfect, linux kernel update fixed the problem. I can now read my kernel messages :) Thanks!

Comment: This issue was also causing me a huge delay when logging in. Updating the kernel fixed both problems. Thanks a lot!

Comment: glad it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

As you write, xhci_hcd is the kernel module (driver) for USB 3.0, and it appears to cause similar problems in other systems. Maybe you should file a bug report, because I do not see a question in what you have posted here.

Comment: I should probably file a bug report as this appears to be a long standing bug. Where is the appropriate place to file this and is there some diagnostics I can use with the filing?

Comment: See the answer by @green7. Use the existing bug report to share your experience or just click "Yes, it affects me".

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue for the second day in a row without changing anything to my setup of USB devices where all of them have been working fine for months. I found that [restarting USB](http://davidjb.com/blog/2012/06/restartreset-usb-in-ubuntu-12-04-without-rebooting/) helps in my case to get my devices back to being detected by the kernel.

Determine the addresses of your controllers:

```
lspci | grep USB
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
```

In this case they are `00:14.0`, `00:1a.0` and `00:1d.0`. Yours my be different.

Unbind and rebind each controller through its address:

```
echo -n "0000:00:14.0" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind
echo -n "0000:00:14.0" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind
```

In my case just doing it just for the xHCI controller was enough and all devices showed up again in `lsusb`. During my analysis I unplugged almost all USB devices and cycled power on the ones with an external power supply, which I recommend in such cases.

Obviously, since USB is not working and all your input devices are probably USB, you need some kind of remote access like SSH.